# Network/Graph Analysis Beginner Resources

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, graph-theory, social-network, igraph

I am a beginner to Network/Graph Analysis. I have data in the following format:

**Customer | CustomerSpend**

Anna                    $10

Bob                     $30

Charlie                 $50

...

...

**Customer1 | Customer2 | RelationshipStrength | Location**

Anna          Bob            5                      NY

Bob           Charlie        10                     TX

...

...

- I want to visualize and conduct some analysis on the data set (which groups spend most, which locations spend most, etc.).
- I am thinking of using NodeXL or igraph (in R) to get started.
- I also want to brush up on graph theory to understand the various metrics I could look at.

What resources can I leverage to get started?